# Asus vivobook S5402ZA keyboard is not working

Tags: keyboard, asus

I have Asus vivobook S5402ZA laptop with a fresh ubuntu 22.04 installation, updated to the latest version.
The touch pad and hotkeys are working but the main laptop keyboard is not working.

- The keyboard is working in the bios self diagnosis and worked well in windows 11.
  Can someone please have a look?

Answer (score 1):

It is a kernel bug regarding IRQ. It is being fixed for all Asus Vivobook laptops here:

https://lore.kernel.org/linux-acpi/CAJZ5v0g=x2cBoFjOufOD6_4nLHhRqoFmM+4BHtWFifVGgNcKUQ@mail.gmail.com/T/#t
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216158

I added the request for the S5402ZA myself as I also have this laptop, but it turned out Canonical already submitted it

Comment: I have a K3502ZA Vivobook. Could you confirm once the changes are made.